# Origami/accordion effect on Android

Tags: android, accordion, folding

Can anyone tell me is there a tutorial out there to acheive similar to this on Android mobile devices?

[GIF Image](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYOrigami/blob/master/Demo/Demo.gif)

[YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltomVYPaV34)

I have looked online but I dont even know what this effect is called? Searching for origami returns origami apps and searching for accordion returns, well, accordion apps.

Comment: did you find how to do? I'd be interested in !

Comment: Dont know if I found a solution, but did find this on YouTube http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rs9mSnWDlZo Havent watched it from start to finish so could not tell you if it will help, skipped to the end and it looks like its what I will need.

Answer (score 0):

for the accordion effect you can check this github library : [Android Accordion View](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view#android-accordion-view)

and check how to use the DrawerLayout [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

and please give me some feedback

Hope That Helps .

Answer (score 0):

May be this github library can help you: https://github.com/7heaven/bitmapMesh

Answer (score 0):

Can you look this site? Quartz Composer Tools export android or ios code.

http://facebook.github.io/origami/

And you can rove github gist.
https://gist.github.com/mustafasevgi/d49c31467053e80a9012